# How to fill a str column with spaces to force a desired length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, format

I need to prepare a pandas DataFrame to write a TXT for submission to a third party on a strict format. When I use the following code directly it seems to work:

```
data['code'].apply(lambda x: '{:>{fill}}'.format(x, fill=15))
```

Bu when I try to actually change the DataFrame like:

```
data['code'] = data['code'].apply(lambda x: '{:>{fill}}'.format(x, fill=15))
```

It doesn't seem to take. How do I actually change the DataFrame?

Answer (score 3):

Check with `ljust` or `zfill`

```
data['code'] = data['code'].str.ljust(width = 15, fillchar = ':')
```